# Dismissing Keyboard in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, keyboard, touchableopacity

I have multiple components in my app where I get user inputs using a keyboard.
Now I want to dismiss the keyboard whenever user presses outside of the text input field.

I know there is **TouchableWithoutFeedback** in which I can wrap my component, but whats the best way to do it for multiple screens having this issue.

Shall I create a HOC for this that handles **TouchableWithoutFeedback** ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
    // Rest of your code
    </ScrollView
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works out of the box for me.

```html
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView } from "react-native";

const KeyboardDismissibleView = ({ backgroundColor = "#F5F4FF", children }) => {
    return <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10, backgroundColor }}>
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{ flex: 1 }} keyboardDismissMode="interactive">
            {children}
        </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
}

export default KeyboardDismissibleView;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Either add an HTML stub so that the snippet will run properly, or format it as a regular code block.

Answer (score -1):

HOC is the best approach imo

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, View } from 'react-native';

const DismissKeyboardHOC = (Comp) => {
  return ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <Comp {...props}>
        {children}
      </Comp>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
export const DismissKeyboardView = DismissKeyboardHOC(View)
```

Comment: This is working fine but the problem in my case is that the children cosnsist of a Flatlist and the Flatlist isn't scrolling at all when indside TouchableWithoutfeedback.

Answer (score -1):

For someone like me who wants to hide the keyboard on click of a `FlatList`, you have to use the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop as follows:

```
<FlatList
   data
   ...otherProps
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
/>
```